# URLs Python Issues

Tags: python, django, django-views

I put this function in `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpRequest('Hello Ahmed')
```

and I include it in `urls.py` like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

But when I go to the URL it gives me this issue:

```
 TypeError at /
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.0.1
```

Comment: The code you have posted would not give that error. Either you have `path(r'^$/', ...)` somewhere in your project, or you have not saved your code/restarted your server after changing to `path('', ...)`.

Comment: sorry,i post issue before i save after i save and run server it give me this issue             TypeError at /
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: The code you have posted shouldn’t give that error. Please update your question with your actual code and the full traceback.

Comment: ok,i update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should return a response, not a request.

```
from django.http import HttpReponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello Ahmed')
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

try this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: i used it before but it gives me that issue WARNINGS:
?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern '^$' [name='index'] has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. T
his was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().

Comment: This is the wrong way round - `path(r'^$', ...)` gives the warning and `path(r'', )` is correct.

Comment: @Roma `path()` is new in Django 2.0. In earlier versions the code above won't work, you've got to use `url()` instead.